# Bash script to iterate over files and replace string

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a script file, that iterates over all files in a given start folder recursivly.

Within each file it then should replace a string.

The files look like the following

```
...

( value1= "FOO")
...
...
( value2= "BAR")
...
```

FOO and BAR are different for each file, but I want to replace the string of value2 (in this case BAR) with the string of value1 (in this case FOO).

Comment: So what do you have so far? What worked? What did not?

Comment: Is it important that value2 remains in the same place in the file?

Comment: Take a look at `sed` and `find`. Come back when you have code that does not work for some specific reason. SO is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Might wanna take a look at `awk` and `grep` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works! Using `GNU grep` for identifying the search pattern and `perl` for in-place replacement.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r -d '' filename
do
    value1=$(grep -oP '(?<=value1=\s").*(?=")' "$filename")
    value2=$(grep -oP '(?<=value2=\s").*(?=")' "$filename")
    perl -pi.bak -e "s/\( value1= ".*"\)/(\ value1= \"$value2\"\)/;" -e "s/\( value2= ".*"\)/(\ value1= \"$value1\"\)/" "$filename"        
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Remove the `-i.bak` once to see if the replacement file is displayed properly in `stdout`, once confirmed add the flag back.

Comment: Can't you just do something like this: `find . -type f -exec grep 'variable1' {}  | awk -F\"  '{print $2}' | xargs sed command here;` ?

Comment: @dramzy : Appreciate your suggestion. I always use the -print0 option to find files with space or special characters in them for a more robust handling. Anyway mine looks more readable, easy to maintain I guess.